# Fixed width element collapses on Mac

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, heroku

I'm creating a website for my brother, a digital animator, using Rails 4. The header consists of a centered title and a four button navbar, made up of a `ul` and `inline-block`'ed `li`s. To get the `ul` to center, i fixed the width to `526px`. To me, on my development Linux machine, using Chrome, the header looks like this:

[image: Linux View]

After deploying to Heroku, I checked out the page on my windows machine:

[image: Windows View]

I send the link to my brother, who works on a Mac with Chrome:

[image: Mac View]

The nav buttons are collapsed and run into a second line. Now, on my computers, no matter how i resize the page, the buttons never collapse in the same way:

[image: Second Linux View]

...What? Why? What is going on? How can I fix this?

---

Here is the header code, which has some embedded ruby to help with the current page:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_title">
        <a href="/" class="nolink">
        <p <% if current_page(request.fullpath) == 6 %> class="header_current_page" <% end %>>
            <span class="name">anSon adamS</span> | <span class="des"> Digital artiSt</span>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="header_navbar">
    <ul class="navbar_ul">
        <li 
        <% if current_page(request.fullpath) == 3 %> class="current_page" <% end %>>
            <span class="li_wrapper">
                <a href="/design">3D Design</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li <% if current_page(request.fullpath) == 4 %> class="current_page" <% end %>>
            <span class="li_wrapper">
                <a href="/art">Digital Art</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li <% if current_page(request.fullpath) == 5 %> class="current_page" <% end %>>
            <span class="li_wrapper">
                <a href="/effects">Visual Effects</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li
        <% if current_page(request.fullpath) == 2 %> class="current_page" <% end %>>
            <span class="li_wrapper">
                <a href="/about">About</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the relevant sass (scss):

```
#header {
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width:526px;
    li {
        display:inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding:5px 15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-style:none;
        border-bottom-style:none;
        border-right-color: rgba(40,40,40,1);
        border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
        border-width: 0px 2px 0px 1px;
        margin: 0px -2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        a {
            margin:5px;
            font-size:11pt;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: inherit;
        }
    }
    li:hover {
        color:$lightblue;
        background-color:#262620;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #2428AD;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which browser is your brother using? Is he also using Chrome?

Comment: It's most likely padding or margin issue. Also note that, if you use custom fonts, the font weight would look different on MACs, best to find bold version of the font and use it than applying standard 'font-weight: bold'. I've had issues where words would drop off from "perfectly" aligned box in macs, just because bold was translated differently.

Comment: @JoeKennedy yes, he also tried it in Safari but the result is the same, which is why I think the problem is OS specific. editing for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just set the `ul` to `text-align: center`? You don't need a fixed width at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/jPN8f/

Comment: that's a good point, and thank you for providing me with that, but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Did you take a look at the link I posted? Remove `width:526px` from the ul and add `text-align: center`. That's all I did to the code you posted.

Comment: i did, and that is the change i applied.

Comment: actually, it didn't look like it was working due to a server error, your method fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you if you provided a generated output of your html and css, but I'll take a guess. Try less lateral `padding` on the `li` element. Start with `li { padding:5px 14px; }` and decrease by 1px if 14 doesn't do it.

I had a similar problem where it was breaking on Safari (Mac and iOS) but not anywhere else. I found out it was 1px of lateral padding (padding-left and padding-right) that was breaking the layout. Here is a test case of that similar problem: http://codepen.io/Tresva/pen/tfFjJ

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the width on the `ul`  and apply `text-align: center` . if not make sure you have `margin:0 auto` on parent divs. - untested